# Significance of -Werror=old-style-cast?

Tags: c++

I'm using code that casts some ints to floats for division.

```
size_t a;
uint8_t b, c;

a = (float)b / (float)c;
```

I was compiling with warning flags enabled and I got one for 'old cast'. Is there a better or proper way I should be casting these things? If so, how?

Comment: Let me ask you something: Do you know exactly what a C-style cast does? If not, don't use it, as it will go all out to try to do what you tell it to, and the results can easily be unexpected. If you do know, you shouldn't *want* to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Old style casts are "C-style" casts.
`-Werror=old-style-cast` turns the usage of C-style casts into errors.
You should use the [C++ casts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

Here you can use a `static_cast` :

```
size_t a; uint8_t b, c;

a = static_cast<float>(b) / static_cast<float>(c);
```

Comment: Thanks. At a low level how does this compare t oa C style cast?